# Cannot bind combobox to an array

Tags: wpf, binding, combobox

I cannot seem to bind my `ComboBox` to an array.

I have this `ObjectDataProvider`:

```
<ObjectDataProvider x:Key="TypeFromEnum" MethodName="GetValues" ObjectType="{x:Type system:Enum}">
    <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
        <x:Type TypeName="property:Property:PropertyType"/>
    </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
</ObjectDataProvider>
```

And this binding:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="TypeCellTemplate">
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path={StaticResource TypeFromEnum}}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Type}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

But I get the error:

> Invalid resource type: expected type is 'PropertyPath', actual type is 'Array'.

And when I run my program and try to open the window with this `ComboBox`, then it crashes:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll
>       Additional information: 'Provide value on 'System.Windows.Markup.TypeExtension' threw an exception.' Line number '8' and line position '12'.
>
> If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `ObjectDataProvider` as `Source` of `Binding` not `Path`:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource TypeFromEnum}}" />
```

Comment: what is the exception now?

Comment: It is still the same as above (in my question)

Comment: `<x:Type TypeName="property:Property:PropertyType"/>` this is wrong.. specify the correct TypeName i.e if property is your xmlns and PropertyType is your Type then TypeName="property:PropertyType"/>

Comment: Yes, but my enum is inside the class Property which is inside the namespace that is stored in property, if I move the enum outside the class then it all works. Is there a way to keep the enum inside my class?